# How to put 2 for loops inside a for loop

Tags: java, loops

So a woman can only have multiple children if she gives birth to a boy - if she gives birth to a girl, she can no longer have any children. I have to create a table showing the results of running 10 simulations, each consisting of the ratio of boys to girls born to 10,000 mothers under this policy. We'll assume that every birth results in a single child (no twins, triplets, etc.), that every child lives, and that the odds of having a boy is 50%.

So far I have:

```
    for (numSimulation = 0; numSimulation < 10; numSimulation++){;
        for (int mothers = 1; mothers <= 10000; mothers++){;
            int randomNum = randomGenerator.nextInt();

            boolean isMale = randomNum % 2 == 0;

            if (isMale){
                numMales++;
            }
            else{
                numFemales++;
            }}
        femaleToMaleRatio =(double) numFemales / numMales;

    }

    System.out.printf("Run#  M : F%n");
    System.out.printf("%4d  1 : %.5f%n",numSimulation-9, femaleToMaleRatio);
    System.out.printf("%4d  1 : %.5f%n",numSimulation-8, femaleToMaleRatio);
    System.out.printf("%4d  1 : %.5f%n",numSimulation-7, femaleToMaleRatio);
    System.out.printf("%4d  1 : %.5f%n",numSimulation-6, femaleToMaleRatio);
    System.out.printf("%4d  1 : %.5f%n",numSimulation-5, femaleToMaleRatio);
    System.out.printf("%4d  1 : %.5f%n",numSimulation-4, femaleToMaleRatio);
    System.out.printf("%4d  1 : %.5f%n",numSimulation-3, femaleToMaleRatio);
    System.out.printf("%4d  1 : %.5f%n",numSimulation-2, femaleToMaleRatio);
    System.out.printf("%4d  1 : %.5f%n",numSimulation-1, femaleToMaleRatio);
    System.out.printf("%4d  1 : %.5f%n",numSimulation, femaleToMaleRatio);

}}`
```

Where and what would I have to put in that 3rd loop to make it keep running until it gives birth to a girl? And also how would I show the femaleToMaleRatio distinctive to each numSimuation? Because right now it shows the same number for all 10 runs on my System.out.printf

Comment: `Java != JavaScript`

Comment: `for (int mothers = 1; mothers <= 10000; mothers++){;` should be `for (int mothers = 1; mothers <= 10000; mothers++){`

Comment: As John D indicated, you have semicolons after the opening braces of both `for` loops. You need to remove those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the first two loops are correct, apart from the semicolons at the end as others pointed out.

So now for the birthgiving. A mother will give birth. If she gives birth to a boy she will keep on giving birth. If she gives birth to a girl she will stop. Correct? This can be reflected in a while-loop:

```
while(randomGenerator.nextInt() % 2 == 0) { // while we're giving birth to boys
  numMales++; // increment the boys counter
}
numFemales++; // we've stopped giving birth to boys -> we've given birth to a girl and should stop
```

Now for showing the female to male ratio for each simulation. Simpy output the female to male ratio after each simulation is don i.e at the end of the first for-loop.

The complete code might look something like this

```
for (int numSimulation = 0; numSimulation < 10; numSimulation++) {

  // reset the boys and girls counter before each simulation
  int numMales = 0;
  int numFemales = 0;
  double femaleToMaleRatio = 1;

    for (int mothers = 1; mothers <= 10000; mothers++) { // here the simulation starts

      while(randomGenerator.nextInt() % 2 == 0) { // while we're giving birth to boys
          numMales++; // increment the boys counter
      }
      // we've stopped giving birth to boys -> we've given birth to a girl and should stop
      numFemales++;
    }

  // we only need to calculate the female to male ratio after the simulation is done
  femaleToMaleRatio = (double) numFemales / numMales;

  // then we print the result of our simulation once its done
  System.out.printf("%4d  1 : %.5f%n", numSimulation, femaleToMaleRatio);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks! One question, you put double femaleToMaleRatio = 1, why? Should it be 0 because there's no child births yet?

Comment: You could set it to be something else, it doesn't really matter in the end since we will be assigning it a new value with `femaleToMaleRatio = (double) numFemales / numMales;`. I choose to set it to 1 because it felt right (but now that you pointed it out i can see that it wasn't logical). you can of course change it to be whatever you like. Like 0 or just don't assign it a value at all (`double femaleToMaleRatio;`).

Comment: @aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa im happy to see that my post was helpful :). If you think it answered your question could you please mark my post as the answer to your question. That would certainly make me happy

Answer (score 1):

I would do a while(! isFemale){//Do randomnumber generator, if male then male++ if female then increment the female variable and set female boolean equal to true. The next time it tries to go into the while loop it'll stop cause female is true.} This while loop should come after the other two for loops. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

hope it can help you all

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int numMales = 0;
        int numFemales = 0;
        int numSimulation = 0;
        double femaleToMaleRatio = 0;

        System.out.printf("Run#  M : F%n");

        for (numSimulation = 0; numSimulation < 10; numSimulation++) {
            for (int mothers = 1; mothers <= 10000; mothers++) {
                int randomNum = randInt(0,1);

                boolean isMale = randomNum % 2 == 0;

                boolean isFemale = false;
                while(!isFemale){
                    isFemale = randInt(0,1) == 0;
                }

                if (isMale) {
                    numMales++;
                } else {
                    numFemales++;
                }
            }
            femaleToMaleRatio = (double) numFemales / numMales;

            System.out.printf("%4d  1 : %.15f%n", numSimulation, femaleToMaleRatio);
        }

    }

    public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

        return randomNum;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this hope this helps

```
for (numSimulation = 0; numSimulation < 10; numSimulation++){
       boolean isfemale=false;
        for (int mothers = 1; mothers <= 10000; mothers++){
            int randomNum = randomGenerator.nextInt();
         do{
            boolean isMale = randomNum % 2 == 0;

            if (isMale){
                numMales++;
            }
            else{
                isfemale=true;
                numFemales++;
            }
         }while(!isfemale);
        }
        femaleToMaleRatio =(double) numFemales / numMales;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off of what Ashwin Shenoy said:
In order to do this you have to basically make a recursive call (or a while statement) after having a boy, but not a girl.

This would look something like:

```
public static double getFemaleToMaleRatio() {
    // total number of runs
    int numberOfRuns = 0;
    // total number of females
    int numFemales = 0;
    // total number of males
    int numMales = 0;

    // run n number of times
    while(numberOfRuns < 10) {
        int mothers = 0;
        while(mothers < 10000) {
            // keep running here until "makeBabyGirl()" returns true
            while(!makeBabyGirl()) {
                numMales++;
            }

            // once "makeBabyGirl()" returns true, it breaks the while loop and increments "numFemales"
            numFemales++;
            mothers++;
        }
        numberOfRuns++;
        System.out.printf("Ratio: %s\n", (double) numFemales/ numMales);
    }
    System.out.printf("Final Ratio: %s\n", (double) numFemales/ numMales);
    return (double) numFemales/ numMales;
}

public static boolean makeBabyGirl() {
    // 50% change of having a boy or girl
    boolean isFemale = Math.random() < 0.5;
    return isFemale;
}
```

You could leave your 2 for loops and just add the new while loop to check if the baby is female as well.